# How to build a string with tags through nested class?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, recursion, dom

Could you please help me to build a html document by nested classes?

My main aim is to build a string with html markup like this

```
<html>
  <div>
    <p>123</p>
    <div>
      <div>
        123
        <a>123</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

I have a class `DOMElement` with the following fileds:

```
class DOMElement {
    TagName :string;
    TextContent: string | null;
    Attributes: string[];
    AttributesValue: string[];
    Children: DOMElement[]; // stored nested tags;
}
```

So I already have a DOM structure of my document with this class, and I want to return this into markup.

For this I used an incorrect method:

```
public convertToHtml (domTree: DOMElement, str: string = ''): string {
    if (domTree.Children.length != 0) {
        domTree.Children.forEach((x) => {
            let attributes = '';
            x.Attributes.forEach((attr, index) => {
                attributes += attr + '=' + `${x.AttributesValue[index]}"`;
            });
            if (x.Children.length != 0) {
                x.TextContent = '';
            }

            str += `<${x.TagName.toLowerCase()} ${attributes}>${this.convertToHtml(
                x,
                str,
            )}${x.TextContent}</${x.TagName.toLowerCase()}>`;
        });
    }

    return str;
};
```

How to fix this recursion to make it return a markup structure? Or are there other options to create markup with a nested object?

Comment: Your code formatting could use some attention to enhance clarity

Comment: What is the `str` parameter represent?

Comment: @code I think the `str` is the input for the recursive function. It defaults to `''` and gets appended to each time. The recursive call uses `convertToHtml(..., str)`

Comment: @ehhh you should include an example of the input you want to run through this function. We have the `DOMElement` type and the example output, but the corresponding input that should produce that output would help too.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about your code? Also, did you add the quotes on accident? `${'attributes'}`

Comment: @code I have a very nested tree, with several dozen nested elements inside other elements etc. And it is well-formed. At the output, I would like to get the complete html structure as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were several typos/small mistakes in the code that added up. Here is a working example with no real changes other than typo fixes:

```js
interface DOMElement {
    TagName: string;
    TextContent: string | null;
    Attributes: string[];
    AttributesValue: string[];
    Children: DOMElement[]; // stored nested tags;
}

const convertToHtml = (domTree: DOMElement, str = ''): string => {
    let result = str;
    if (domTree.Children.length !== 0) {
        domTree.Children.forEach((child) => {
            let attributes = child.Attributes.length > 0 ? '"' : '';
            child.Attributes.forEach((attr, index) => {
                attributes += `${attr}=${child.AttributesValue[index]}"`;
            });
            if (child.Children.length !== 0) {
                child.TextContent = '';
            }

            result += `<${child.TagName.toLowerCase()} ${attributes}>${convertToHtml(
                child,
                str,
            )}${child.TextContent}</${child.TagName.toLowerCase()}>`;
        });
    }

    return result;
};

const sampleInput = {
    TagName: '',
    TextContent: '',
    Attributes: [],
    AttributesValue: [],
    Children: [
        {
            TagName: 'html',
            TextContent: '',
            Attributes: [],
            AttributesValue: [],
            Children: [
                {
                    TagName: 'div',
                    TextContent: '',
                    Attributes: ['ok'],
                    AttributesValue: ['test'],
                    Children: [
                        {
                            TagName: 'p',
                            TextContent: '123',
                            Attributes: [],
                            AttributesValue: [],
                            Children: [],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};

console.log(convertToHtml(sampleInput));
// <html ><div "ok=test"><p >123</p></div></html>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHkCyBRANhAWwnGQG8BYAKGRuQBU4BzAOTiIC5kBnMKURgNxVa9CAA8wAYQD24YmE48+IRsgA+yEAFdcuIdVoBBML2AAjLZC6LTKgNoBdfSOOmLVgGpxcWiDeWMjs60kgAWwLgAJlDEnBg4+ETgQcgA9KncYNIxkZoQPBC5YExc+gC+VFQIsjzI1SAAbtBgdNIAEmAEuMgAvMgAFJHSBHQxfmhYeITyADSZUL3IAORLAJT+-L0AfGTCtPhgyDFcOod9SsE0wDADQyNjAHRhEdHED-gqYKHIAIQ9fQAGVa7AwiGh3UYQCBPcJRGIgB4wbLYRChfr9BCwyLAno7CigsEiA7IOAmPjufKLTEvB6ucmWfLvYiML7IHYA5AAfmWACIlshOCtLoTaNSorSyeYGVxEcjUejSbw5qBIuIcXi9iKRYr6VZkABqPoAAwAJKQdWUemaxZEJW5pV4fBA7CrxA4yjyjcKtWVVt6RdcBjaYS94UzPt8-oDgfitVrg3RxFJZJASH0hZq4xVKJmtcdTgbjQAea1Yh4MFhsaFZAAy0gA7tBJHAuBB+qsysgzTqpVYyltrbImlAWu1Orh+rm4zQbTMp9OlHOCVqO6WaYmJDI5OAykXUmvxRXWEQHrWG02W22O1svfPkL7hdnMzEwFooCAjvlTuV9FUaocuDYAAHfAAEkQCAyxFljWgjyrQUliXEQN2TbcFGWRDMzpXt8k4RwkKMSUKS4R1fDwhwCJoZ44ViZA7DvGDpzgjhllCcdMOXEUUK3VN0JWSi42w4jyIErUhIdbwyLoii7xEajXhAPDZJFRjpy4phj3GJZImABoOLUuNuJTeQENEgzCPtKw8KWaQAGslhkzjzOQcTPEk8Y7CWKwwAcsznPk+ElKc5zaFUkLDI0+DliA-TwrUoy0MFABGAAmABmWK4sEojpRE5Sstc-JSI8xysunALaPw-LzLKPzzNKkLauqhrCSaglHLKX9KHqLhpHwd5pEYDEh2aVoOi6fpAIIECIHAyCwFWP0qHSZAizYro2SLHSGmQHk7J6byeS2IsgLZVK0r3IDjtSbbrvW3AtiAA)

### Extra Notes/Suggestions/Tips

#### `class` vs. `interface`

`DOMElement` was a `class`, but it could also have been an `interface` or a `type`. In this case, it looks like you're not using it as a `class` really, so a TS type is probably better.

#### Default argument value type inference

You used `str: string = ''` as an argument, but TS can infer that it's a string already when you specify `''` as the default.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle this. I have a function I call 'createHTMLElement'.

```
const createHTMLElement = (data) => {

    let element = document.createElement(data.type)

    if(data.UUID) element.setAttribute('data-UUID', data.UUID)
    if(data.id) element.id = data.id
    if(data.class) element.className = data.class
    if(data.click) element.addEventListener('click', data.click)
    if(data.blur) element.addEventListener('blur', data.blur)
    if(data.focus) element.addEventListener('focus', data.focus)
    if(data.innerHTML) element.innerHTML = data.innerHTML
    if(data.innerText) element.innerText = data.innerText
    if(data.attribute) element.setAttribute(data.attribute.key, data.attribute.value)
    if(data.attributes){
        for(attribute of data.attributes){
            element.setAttribute(attribute.key, attribute.value)
        }
    }
    if(data.child) element.appendChild(data.child)
    if(data.children){
        for(child of data.children){
            element.appendChild(child)
        }
    }
    if(data.title) element.title = data.title
    if(data.value) element.value = data.value
    if(data.placeholder) element.placeholder = data.placeholder

    return element
}
```

I create JSON objects that look like this:

```
let obj = {
    "UUID": this._UUID, 
    "type": "div",
    "class": "divClass",
    "id": "divID",
    "click": functionYouWantToRun,  
    "child": childHTMLElement,
    "attribute":{
    "key": attributeName,
    "value": attributeValue
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
let ele = createHTMLElement(obj)
```

The ele that is returned will be a dom object. Instead of passing a single child, it can take an array (passed as 'children') to add multiple at one time. Maybe this, or some tweaked version, can help you get what you're looking for.